# My exported and re-imported sql database has more rows than original

Tags: mysql

I exported a database from my localhost xampp's phpmyadmin with `mysqldump -u root -p DB1 > exported.sql` and re-imported it in a newly created DB2 by `mysql -u root -p DB2 < exported.sql` the import looks successful, but for some reason that I can't determine, one of the 3 tables in the database has `677.285` rows instead of `664.164`. The re-imported database has more rows.  I repeated the process with same result. Has this happened to anyone before? What information other than the actual DB could I provide to help diagnose this?

Comment: How have you counted the rows in the tables?

Comment: Thanks to the deleted comment and to @Progman to remind me to try to find a function to count rows and not to trust the phpmyadmin GUI.